# UNIX AIX using Array to store name and path then get them using for loop separately

Tags: aix, array

I have a script in which i need to create an array with the Path and Name of some files,

then i need to pass the Path and Name separately to another script after checking the user's arg matching one of the Names in the arrray

```
array1[0]="/Distenation1/File1.txt"
array1[1]="file1"

#testing another way to set an array
set -A array2 "/Distenation2/File2.txt" file2
```

Here comes the problem as i cant find a way to pass the array as whole and then inside the for loop i want to match the user **arg $1** with **file1** or **file2** and so on, and pass the corresponding path to another script :

```
#the following code doesnt work as needed -logically-
for i in ${array1[@]} ${array2[@]}
do
        if [ $1 = ${i[1]} ]
        then
                ./sendfile ${i[0]}
        fi;
done
```

Edit :
ksh version as appeared to me = Version M-11/16/88f

using the same code as above but with echo to show an example :

code:

```
for i in ${array1[@]} ${array2[@]}
do
    echo Name : ${i[1]} '\n'Path : ${i[0]}
done
```

Output :

```
Name :
Path : /Distenation1/file1.txt
Name :
Path : file1
Name :
Path : /Distenation2/file2.txt
Name :
Path : file2
```

Needed Result should be :

```
Name : file1
Path : /Distenation1/file1.txt
Name : file2
Path : /Distenation2/file2.txt
```

Comment: You seem to be manually recreating associative arrays; or, manually creating a series of two-element arrays. Why have you created array1 and array2? Is there an array3? Are there more elements in array1 or array2? It seems to me that you could use an associative array keyed on the "name" with values being the paths? What shell are you using? ksh, or ksh93?

Comment: What shell are you using? This would be more important to know than what Unix you're running in this case.  You also do not say anything about what you want your loop to do, only that it "doesn't work".

Comment: @JeffSchaller The code as it is will be having more variables to store paths either arrays or else if it gives the needed result, as for what ksh iam using ... iam not sure, will check tomorrow at work.

Comment: @JeffSchaller i used an array declaration like this array[name]="name" & array[value]="dir" but it gave me an error i can post it tomorrow too

Comment: @Kusalananda iam explaining before the code what is needed then iam posting the "not logically working" code, as for what shell iam using i will check on that tomorrow as iam not an Admin iam a limited user (physically & in knowledge)

Comment: @Kusalananda i should be posting examples of output result vs needed result, will do that too

Answer (score 0):

i tried a work around which i think i understand :

```
#put all the data inside 1 array
array1[0]="/Distenation1/File1.txt"
array1[1]="file1"
array1[2]="/Distenation2/File2.txt"
array1[3]="file2"

#create a counter    
n=0

#the trick here was that 'i' (loop) stores 1 array data per iteration (at first i thought it stores the whole array data then go through them 1 by one)
for i in ${array1[@]}
do
        if [ $1 = ${i} ]
        then
#here i had to call the original array to be able to read through any data inside the array
                echo Name : $i '\n' Path : ${array1[$n+1]}
        fi;

        let n=n+1
done;
```

OUTPUT :

```
=>test1 file1
Name : file1
 Path : /Distenation1/File1.txt
```

I am not sure if its the best practice but i am open to any better solution or optimized code as i am working with a really big script and every millisecond of optimization will make a difference